# Write clever Javascript

Tags: javascript

this is a very dummy question for all the experts here I suppose.

I have a bunch of if statements (16), and I'm trying to find a way to write 48 lines of code in much less because I'm sure it's possible.

I've read everywhere that long if/else if statements are bad practices.

So how to write this bunch of code the clever way? Thanks

```
  if (!latitude || typeof latitude == 'undefined') {
    latitude == 'undefined';

  } else if( !longitude || typeof longitude == 'undefined' ) {
    longitude == 'undefined';

  } else if( !name || typeof name == 'undefined' ) {
    name == 'undefined';

  } else if( !adresseNum || typeof adresseNum == 'undefined' ) {
    adresseNum == 'undefined';

  } else if( !adresseVille || typeof adresseVille == 'undefined' ) {
    adresseVille == 'undefined';

  } else if( !adresseDpt || typeof adresseDpt == 'undefined' ) {
    adresseDpt == 'undefined';

  } else if( !adresseRg || typeof adresseRg == 'undefined' ) {
    adresseRg == 'undefined';

  } else if( !adresseFr || typeof adresseFr == 'undefined' ) {
    adresseFr == 'undefined';

  } else if( !adresseCp || typeof adresseCp == 'undefined' ) {
    adresseCp == 'undefined';

  } else if( !telephone || typeof telephone == 'undefined' ) {
    telephone == 'undefined';

  } else if( !horaires || typeof horaires == 'undefined' ) {
    horaires == 'undefined';

  } else if( !note || typeof note == 'undefined' ) {
    note == 'undefined';

  } else if( !reviewFinale || typeof reviewFinale == 'undefined' ) {
    reviewFinale == 'undefined';

  } else if( !website || typeof website == 'undefined' ) {
    website == 'undefined';

  } else if( !types || typeof types == 'undefined' ) {
    types == 'undefined';

  } else {
    console.log('All fields OK');
  }
```

Comment: A ``switch`` statement might help you here. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: are you sure about the `else if` pattern? are the values not independent to check and assign?

Comment: Create a function

Comment: is an empty string a valid content?

Comment: You also do not need the second part of the conditions, undefined variables will pass the first condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ES6, you could use an object with all variables as key and value pair, then iterate with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and assign on falsy values `undefined` and check the result with an `if statement`.

```
var data = { latitude, longitude, name, adresseNum, adresseVille, adresseDpt, adresseRg, adresseFr, adresseCp, telephone, horaires, note, reviewFinale, website, types };

if (Object.keys(data).every(k => data[k] || (data[k] = 'undefined', false))) {
    console.log('All fields OK');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var isOk = [
  latitude, 
  longtitude, 
  name, 
  adresseNum, 
  adresseVille, 
  adresseDpt, 
  adresseRg, 
  adresseFr, 
  adresseCp, 
  telephone, 
  horaires, 
  note, 
  reviewFinale, 
  website, 
  types
].every(function (value) {
  return !!value;
});

if (isOk) {
  console.log('All fields OK');
}
```

But I think you'd better combine all variables to object or form

Comment: Using es6 that would be possible easily with a slight change to your answer

Comment: @user7951676, I don't quite understand where ES6 will simplify something here, can you give me a clue?

Comment: You can put them into an object like {var1,var2} and the keys will be the variable names than a for in loop unless there's an object method to iterate over all keys too

Comment: Oh it's Nina's answer here :) And I don't think adding ES6 simplifies things for this particular question, to be honest. It's just another aproach

Answer (score 2):

you can do a function that checks them all like this

```
var isDefined = [latitude, longtitude, name, adresseNum, adresseVille, adresseDpt, adresseRg, adresseFr, adresseCp, telephone, horaires, note, reviewFinale, website, types].every(function (value) {return !!value;});
```

Answer (score 0):

is every variable defined by itself or is it coming from another object or similar to `var telephone = obj.telephone`?

if that is the case you could do something like this:

```
var ok = true;
for (var o in obj) {
    if (!obj[o]) {
        obj[o] == 'undefined';
        ok = false;
    }
}

if (ok) {
    console.log('all fields are ok');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An option that might works is using default value in argument destructure. Basically you check for every variable if it's undefined (by the way, what happens if one of those are the value 'false'?).
This is specific for this case though...

```
function functionWithSomeLogic({
    latitude = 'undefined',
    longitude = 'undefined',
    name = 'undefined',
    adresseNum = 'undefined'
    // ... and the rest of the variables
}) {
    // Do whatever here, all the arguments are initialized or have the string value of 'undefined'
}
```

by the way, if instead of setting a default value you would like to throw an exception

```
const throwArg = argName => throw new Error(`Argument missing: ${argName}`);

function functionWithSomeLogic({
    latitude = throwArg('latitude'),
    longitude = throwArg('longitude'),
    name = throwArg('name'),
    adresseNum = throwArg('adresseNum')
    // ... and the rest of the variables
}) {
    // Do whatever here, all the arguments are initialized, if one of them
    // had been undefined, an appropriate exception will be thrown before this body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple es6 function will do the trick. as @Andrey pointed out.

`const areDefined = (...args) => args.every(elm => !!elm);
if(areDefined(latitude, longitude, name/*, ...*/)) {
    console.log('All fields OK');
}`